# How can i do an async countdown in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So i'm trying to do a countdown from 30 to 0, i'm waiting 3.75s with the setInterval because i want to do a oxygen bar after that

the function air() who is supposed to be the countdown

```
async function air(){
    var timer;
    var barre_oxygene = 6;
    var ele = plateau[14][5]
    timer = setInterval(()=>{
        ele.innerHTML = 30 - 1;
    }, 1000)
}
```

The init of the 2d array :

```
function initPlateau() {
  plateau = new Array(hauteur);
  for (let i = 0; i < hauteur; i++) {
    plateau[i] = new Array(largeur);
  }
  let contenu = document.querySelector("#contenu");
  let monTableau = document.createElement("table");
  // lignes 
  for (let i = 0; i < hauteur; i++) {
    let uneLigne = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < largeur; j++) {
      let uneColonne = document.createElement("td");
      uneLigne.appendChild(uneColonne);
      uneColonne.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
      plateau[i][j] = uneColonne;
    }
    monTableau.appendChild(uneLigne);
  }
  contenu.appendChild(monTableau);

  // Set dynamic background image size based on largeur and hauteur
  contenu.style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/header.png'), url('./img/footer.png'), url('./img/middle-image.png')";
  contenu.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  contenu.style.backgroundPosition = "top center, bottom center, top center";
  contenu.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  contenu.style.backgroundSize = `${largeur * 45}px ${hauteur * 9.5}px`;
}
```

When i start the entire program (there is like 200 ligns) the countdown doesn't show up (i need him to pop on the 14th rows on the fifth column.
I have the error "Cannot be read properties of undefined (reading '5')

i tried changing 5 by replacing him with variable

Comment: Your function is declared as an `async` function but it does not return a Promise; in fact it does not return anything.

Comment: It's unclear how do you use the `air` function

Comment: The error suggests that `plateau[14]` is `undefined` which would mean that you didn't initialize the array correctly

Comment: I'm doing Sea Quest game on Javascript, and i'm trying to implement oxygen with a countown from 30s to 0s and i want to put it on the array on the 14th rows and fifth column

Comment: `reading 5` means the element it was reading was null, so `14` is the problem. `hauteur` must not be 15 or larger.  Also, 30 - 1 is always 29, no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: okay i have corrected the error but now it won't work, the countdown stay blocked on 29

Comment: what you really need to check is the values of `hauteur` and `largeur`. If you are trying to access the last entry, they need to be at least 15 and 6.

Comment: 30 - 1 is always 29. You are setting it to 29 every time, so what would you expect?